# Do R sessions always use one CPU core unless specifically instructed otherwise?

Tags: r, foreach, hpc, doparallel

On occasions where heavy compute is required, I've used `doParallel` package to dispatch work over multiple cores. Random example:

```
  if (detectCores()-1 > 1) {
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
    registerDoParallel(cl)

    tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control = list(dictionary = Terms(tdm), removePunctuation = TRUE, stopwords = TRUE, stemming = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE)) 

    stopCluster(cl)
  }
```

But the ***vast*** majority (probably 99.5%) of R code I write is *not* wrapped in additional code that explicitly spread the work across >1 cores.

Is it fair to assume this code is running across 1 single core? Or would answering this require delving into each library used, and its functions (e.g. `tidyverse`, `data.table` etc)?

Note: aside from some timed experiments, I do not know a lot about how R and the hardware interacts, so if my understanding if flawed (e.g. wrong assumptions), please point out.

#### Background

The reason this is of great interest is help decide between fewer cores at higher clock speed vs more cores at lower clock speed; al la the latest macbook. It would be unfortunate to pay more for a 'better' processors, only to have most day-to-day R tasks run slower due to the slower clock speed (presuming they're running only on one core).

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure most R functions (all?) operate on 1 core unless specifically directed to use more through parallel and the like.

Comment: A follow up note for anyone interested. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jm3_JOPl_h0&t=6m35s) ~20 seconds of video shows that for single core tasks, the laptop with fewer cores with higher clock speeds out performed the laptop with more cores and lower clock speeds (in that case, by a touch under 30%)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying and pasting from a Slack discussion we just had on this in another place:

- This is somewhat wrong / it depends / maybe too narrow a view.
- For starters, R itself even uses a little OpenMP (on platforms where it can).
- Next up, you can pick BLAS that do all your matrix math in parallel.
- Next up is client code that can be multi-threaded and often is; package [data.table](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=data.table) is a *great* and famous example.
- And maybe (at least to me) also importantly: if I set `options("Ncpu"=6)` on my six core desktop, I get `install.packages()` to install six packages in parallel.
- Same for `make -j ...`

I say a little more on R and parallel computing (at different levels) in this [arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11144) now out in [this (paywalled) WIREs article](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/wics.1515).

Now, lastly, you say macOS.  That has a slew of other difficulties with OpenMP for which you should peruse the r-sig-mac list and maybe other repo (again, [data.table](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=data.table) covers that).  I don't use macOS so I cannot say much more---other than that I see a lot of people having issues.

Lastly, of course, and not to take away from it:  yes, R's inner interpreter is single-threaded and will remain so.  But that does not mean we should rush out and by single-core computers.  You will get *some* benefits from more cores, but exactly *how much* depends critically on the workloads.